# Average of all subjects except one

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, average

I have a table like

```
Student Subject Marks
John    Maths   80
John    Science 70
John    Social  90
Raju    Maths   90
Raju    Science 80
Raju    Social  70
```

I want the average of maths and rest of all subjects average in a table like as i shown below by Using "Having" clause.

I want O/P like this

```
Subject                   Average

Maths                       85

Rest(of all subjects)       77.5
```

Comment: `select subject, avg(marks) from tbl where subject != 'xxx' group by subject` ?

Comment: @AlexK. guess no need to use **group by subject**

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Some product specific answers below...)

Comment: Given the sample data that you show do you actually just want to return "Maths" and "Rest(of all subj)"? Probably not, so please provide what you **actually** want to see as output.

Comment: @Tom H- i want the avg of Maths sub and Rest of all subjects avg as well

Answer (score 2):

Use a CASE:

```
SELECT
   CASE
     WHEN Subject = 'Math' THEN Subject 
     ELSE 'All Subjects'
   END,
   AVG(Marks)
FROM tab
GROUP BY
   CASE
     WHEN Subject = 'Math' THEN Subject 
     ELSE 'All Subjects'
   END
```

Comment: Can't We do without using CASE ?

Comment: Ya its fine with CASE, but the thing is that as i am new to plsql so i want it in simple way

Comment: @Satish: Almost every DBMS supports `CASE` and there's no simpler way. Ok, there's Oracle's old deprecated `DECODE`, but this is proprietary and not really simpler

Comment: @dnoeth:I want the avg of n( let us say 20) subjects instead of 3 subjects  then what would be the code?

Answer (score 1):

A case statement can be used as a grouping field, like this:

```
select CASE subject WHEN 'Maths' THEN subject ELSE 'Others' END as Subject, 
       AVG(Marks) as Average
from tbl
group by CASE subject WHEN 'Maths' THEN subject ELSE 'Others' END
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's a case expression. (It returns a value.)

Comment: Can we do that in much simple way?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression to do the subject replacement in a derived table. Then do `GROUP BY` on it's result:

```
select subject, avg(marks)
from 
(
    select case when Subject <> 'Maths' then 'Rest(of all subj)' else subject end,
           Marks
    from tablename
) dt
group by subject
```

(Core ANSI SQL-99, plus F591, "Derived tables" feature.)

Without a `CASE`:

```
select Subject, avg(marks)
from
(
select Subject, marks from tablename where Subject = 'Maths'
union all
select 'Rest(of all subj)', marks from tablename where Subject <> 'Maths'
)
group by Subject
```

Or even more simplified, as suggested by dnoeth:

```
select 'Maths' as Subject,  avg(marks) from tablename where Subject = 'Maths'
union all
select 'Rest(of all subj)', avg(marks) from tablename where Subject <> 'Maths'
```

Comment: How about simplifying to: `select Subject, avg(marks) from tablename where Subject = 'Maths'
union all
select 'Rest(of all subj)', avg(marks) from tablename where Subject <> 'Maths'`

Comment: Thanks Jarlh.' <> ' What does it mean?

Comment: @dnoeth, of course... I'll add that one too. Thanks!

Comment: @Satish, `<>` means not equal to, same as `!=`, `/=` etc in some languages.

Comment: I want the avg of n( let us say 20) subjects instead of 3 subjects then what would be the code?

Comment: @Satish, how many of those 20 needs special treatment (like Maths)? I suppose you can basically use the answers already given, perhaps you need an adjustment for special treatment subjects.

Comment: @jarlh: Suppose John and Raju have 20 subjects in common like Maths, Socila,Science, i want the average of all 20 subjects individually. like maths - 70%, science -89%,social -78%,physics -80%.......etc.....upto 20 subjects

Comment: @Satish, then simply remove the CASE and do a regular GROUP BY, i.e. `select Subject, avg(marks) from tablename group by subject`.

Comment: @dnoeth: I want it by using 'Having' clause

Comment: @Satish, why is a `HAVING` clause required?

Comment: @jarlh: I am trying to get the output using HAVING clause

Comment: @Satish, I can read... But can you tell me why you want a HAVING clause?

Comment: @ jarlh: i want that output in a single line query thats why i thought of using HAVING clause

Answer (score 1):

Just a Different way for Conditional Aggregation. Ofcourse it might confuse some.

`AVG(1,2,NULL) = 1.5` , **Not** `1` Because, aggregate functions *exclude* NULLs

```
SELECT
   AVG(CASE
     WHEN Subject = 'Maths' THEN Marks 
     ELSE NULL
   END) "Maths",
 AVG(CASE
     WHEN Subject = 'Maths' THEN NULL 
     ELSE Marks
   END)  "Rest Of All"
FROM tab
```